# Getting the index of the last input field in a series that has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Shortest explanation I can possibly give:

I have 5 (0 through 4) input fields in a row. I want to find the one furthest to the right that is not empty.

For example:

```
[      ] [      ] [      ] [      ] [ xyz   ]
```

The code should return 4, because the input box farthest to the the right is not blank.

One more example:

```
[ 123   ] [      ] [ abc   ] [      ] [      ]
```

The code should return 2, since "abc" is the farthest to the right with data in the input field.

Comment: Have you got some code to show?

Answer (score 4):

See my [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b39CY/)

The Code:

```
<input name="a" type="text" >
<input name="b" type="text" >
    <input name="c" type="text" >
        <input name="d" type="text" >
            <button>LAST ONE</button>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
function func(){
alert($("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value.length !== 0;
}).last().index());
}
$("button").click(function(){
    func();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes that works. return $(this).val(); would be a little neater

Comment: can you please choose my answer. i do not have much reputation.. =(

Comment: Yes, your solution worked perfectly. I was just waiting to see if there were any more interesting ways of doing this. Thank you, Johnny!

Comment: For `=(`, +1.  You deserved it. cuz, you just suggested this method, before every one.

Comment: Actually, how would this work? Wouldn't filter() return an array of all the items that match this criteria, and therefore losing the object's true index position in the original array of input fields?

Comment: @Derek If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection. please read http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var idx;
$('input'/*or whatever the correct selector is*/).each(function(i) {
    if($(this).val()) {
        idx = i;
    }
});
console.log(idx);
```

Comment: This won't return the result the OP is after. OP wants the index not the value

Comment: I was thinking of reversing the array and in an each() block, return the the array's size minus "i" for the first result found. Would this be a good solution? I didn't know if there was a fancier way to do this in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try this out,

<strike>alert($('input:not(:empty)').last().index());</strike>

```
alert($("input[value!='']").last().index());
```

[DEMO updated](http://jsfiddle.net/tX3C9/1/)

or try this,

```
var xTest = $("input").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() != '';   
}).last();


alert(xTest.index());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tX3C9/)

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu, but this gives me the last empty one. I want the index of the last input that is NOT empty.

Comment: Also, this assumes that inputs have the same parent, and that there are no sibling elements.

Comment: @Derek, try `$('input:not(:empty)').last().index()`

Comment: From what I understand, :empty is to ensure that the object has no children, not that a form field has no value. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Derek Yes you are absolutely right, that's y I just provided an alternate solution and still working on to catch it with proper selector. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about starting at the end of your selection and return the first index which has a value? Less iterations needed and better for performance in my opinion:

```
function returnIndex($items) {
    for (var i=$items.length-1; i>0; i--) {
        var $thisItem = ;
        if ($items.eq(i).val()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return $items.eq(0).val() ? 0 : false;
}

console.log(returnIndex($('input'));
```